# Scaledown DataProc workers if not used for Streaming Job

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have DataProc streaming job that being executed a few times a day (most of the time it is idling).

Is that possible to scaledown all workers if not used automatically and pay only for the driver node?

Comment: I think you can do it manually or even script it. But the docs for [autoscaling feature](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/autoscaling) suggest not. `Autoscaling is not recommended for the purpose of scaling a cluster down to minimum size when the cluster is idle.`

Comment: Have you configured the cluster as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/autoscaling#autoscaling_and_spark_streaming